# Creating alternate keyboard shortcut substituting laptop Fn keys for switching to external monitors

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, display

Currently, I am using Fedora 36 on my Zenbook, with an external monitor connected via HDMI.  My laptop has an Fn key for switching among various display configurations, i.e. display 0, display 1, both, etc. Every time I needed to switch, I had to go back to my laptop keyboard as my external keyboard won't support Fn keys.

I have been looking for a solution for creating an alternate key combination on the standard keyboard for this purpose. I looked into some other older q&a (example: [this](https://superuser.com/q/564057/614906) superuser question), but I did not find anything helpful.

Tried looking into [this](https://superuser.com/q/155004/614906), however, `xrandr -q` is giving my output device ids like `XWAYLAND10`, `XWAYLAND11` etc, and they often change. If I try to use these with `--output` options, I get following error

```
[zobayer@banana ~]$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND11 --off
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
Serial number of failed request:  28
Current serial number in output stream:  29
```